# 2 values of different matrices match. Now change another value in same row

Tags: matlab

So I have two matrices, and I want to replace a value in column 2 of Matrix A if the value in column 1 of this matrix A is equal to the value in the first column of Matrix B. This replacement value is the value in Column two of Matrix B.

So: A=

```
1   0
2   Inf
3   Inf
4   Inf
5   Inf
6   Inf
7   Inf
8   Inf
9   Inf
10  Inf
```

And B=

```
5   563,4
7   327,9
```

And I would like:
A=

```
1   0
2   Inf
3   Inf
4   Inf
5   563,4
6   Inf
7   327,9
8   Inf
9   Inf
10  Inf
```

I'm trying (if possible) to avoid using a for-loop, since they are inefficient most of the time. 
Furthermore, I should probably mention that Matrix B changes size on every loop

Comment: So what have *you* done to solve this conundrum? Stack Overflow is not a place to post a requirement and have someone write your code for free. If you read up on [ask], you'll notice that effort into solving the problem yourself needs to be visibly put into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ismember function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), this can be achieved pretty easily:

```
A = [
  1   0
  2   Inf
  3   Inf
  4   Inf
  5   Inf
  6   Inf
  7   Inf
  8   Inf
  9   Inf
  10  Inf
];

B = [
  5   563.4
  7   327.9
];

% Create a logical indexing for the values of
% the first column of A that are present in
% the first column of B...
idx = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1));

% Replace the values of the second column of A
% with the values of the second column of B
% for the indices defined above...
A(idx,2) = B(:,2);
```

Output:

```
A =
     1         0
     2       Inf
     3       Inf
     4       Inf
     5     563.4
     6       Inf
     7     327.9
     8       Inf
     9       Inf
    10       Inf
```

On a side note, the computation performed in the code snipped can also be converted into a one-liner as follows:

```
A(ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)),2) = B(:,2);
```

If you want to replace only the values in `A` that are equal to `Inf`, further steps are needed. Another condition, through the logical operator `&`, must be applied to the indexing in order to match only the correct values. An indexing of `B` towards `A` must be created in order apply the same condition:

```
A = [
  1   0
  2   Inf
  3   Inf
  4   Inf
  5   233.4
  6   Inf
  7   Inf
  8   Inf
  9   Inf
  10  Inf
];

B = [
  5   563.4
  7   327.9
];

A_idx = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)) & (A(:,2) == Inf);
B_idx = (A(ismember(B(:,1),A(:,1)),2) == Inf);
A(A_idx,2) = B(B_idx,2);
```

Output:

```
A =
     1         0
     2       Inf
     3       Inf
     4       Inf
     5     233.4
     6       Inf
     7     327.9
     8       Inf
     9       Inf
    10       Inf
```